# How do I open my app from another one of my apps?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I open an ios app I made, from another ios app I made?

I noticed there are url's I can call to open the google maps app... and other apps but I cant seem to find a straightforward example for how to accomplish this with my own apps.

I tried using the bundle identifier as a url, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the app you wish to open, do this...

click project file > click your main project target > Info tab > URL Types dropdown > add button

in the "URL Schemes" field put the code word you wish to use when you want to open this app.

[image]

in the app you wish to use to open the first app with, do this

- add this to your info.plist [image: info.plist]
- add this code to open your other app

  ```
   @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: "openThisApp://")!

    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
  ```

  }

Calling the buttonTapped() function should now open the app.